# Link drawing issue in d3 force layout

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am starting to learn java script in order to draw graphs and I use several examples to create my script but I don't manage to draw lines between my nodes. My guess is that this is due to attribute declarations starting line 92 but I don't know where is the issue.
Those are the two main examples I used to create my script:

https://codepen.io/jefarrell/pen/ReYKPa
http://www.puzzlr.org/force-directed-graph-minimal-working-example/

this is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #E6E6E6;
    }

    svg {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .node {
        pointer-events: all;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    .node text {
        font: 8px sans-serif;
    }
    div.tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        max-width; 200px;
        height: auto;
        padding: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border-width: 1px;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
        pointer-events: none;
    }
</style>
<script src='d3.min.js'></script>
<script src='d3-tip.js'></script>
</head>
<body style="margin: 5%">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // node data
        var nodes =  [
        {"name": "Travis", "sex": "M","size": 1983},
        {"name": "Rake", "sex": "M","size": 200},
        {"name": "Diana", "sex": "F","size": 15000},
        {"name": "Rachel", "sex": "F","size": 1800},
        {"name": "Shawn", "sex": "M","size": 1983},
        {"name": "Emerald", "sex": "F","size": 10000}
        ]

        //Create links data 
        var links_data = [
            {"source": "Travis", "target": "Rake"},
            {"source": "Diana", "target": "Rake"},
            {"source": "Diana", "target": "Rachel"},
            {"source": "Rachel", "target": "Rake"},
            {"source": "Rachel", "target": "Shawn"},
            {"source": "Emerald", "target": "Rachel"}
        ]
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //toolpit declaration
        var tooltip = d3.select("body")
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("opacity", 0);

        //svg size
        const width = 1000,
        height = 1000;

        // Allow zoom
        const transform = d3.zoomIdentity;

        // Find connected nodes
        var linkedByIndex = {};

        // Append svg info
        const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
        .call(d3.zoom().scaleExtent([1/2, 8]).on('zoom', zoomed))
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(40,0)');

        // graph simulation declaration
        const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force('link', d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
        .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-15).distanceMax(300))
        .force('center', d3.forceCenter( width/2, height/4 ))
        .on('tick', ticked)

        // Function to update graph informations (nodes positions, links....)
        function update(nodes, links_data) {
            //Extract links source and target information
            link = svg
                .selectAll('.links_data')
                .data(links_data, function(d){ return d.source.id })

                .data(links_data, function(d){ return d.target.id })


            link.exit().remove()

            // Custumzie links
            const linkEnter = link
                .enter()
                .append('line')
                .data(link)
                .attr('class', 'link')
                .style('stroke', '#000' )
                .style('opacity', '0.2')
                .style('stroke-width', 2)
                .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.source.y; })

            link = linkEnter.merge(link)

            // Add nodes to svg
            node = svg
                .selectAll('.node')
                .data(nodes, function(d){ return d.id })

            node.exit().remove()

            // Custumzie nodes
            const nodeEnter = node
                .enter()
                .append('g')
                .attr('class', 'node')
                .attr('stroke', '#666')
                .attr('stroke-width', 2)
                .style('fill', color)
                .on("mouseover", focus)
                .on('mouseover.tooltip', function(d) {
                    tooltip.transition()
                    .duration(300)
                    .style("opacity", 0.9);
                    tooltip.html("Label:" + d.name + "<p/>Degree:" + d.size)
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 10) + "px");
                })
                .on('mouseover.fade', fade(0.1))
                .on("mouseout.tooltip", function() {
                    tooltip.transition()
                    .duration(100)
                    .style("opacity", 0);
                })
                .on('mouseout.fade', fade(1))
                .on("mousemove", function() {
                    tooltip.style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 10) + "px");
                })
                .call(d3.drag()
                    .on('start', dragstarted)
                    .on('drag', dragged)
                    .on('end', dragended))


            // Draw nodes
            nodeEnter.append('circle')
                .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; })
                .style('text-anchor', function(d){ return d.children ? 'end' : 'start'; })
                .text(function(d){ return d.name })


            node = nodeEnter.merge(node)
                simulation.nodes(nodes)
                simulation.force('link').links(link)
        }

        function sizeContain(num) {
            num = num > 1000 ? num/1000 : num/100
            if (num < 4) num = 4
                return num
            }

        function color(d) {
            return d._children ? "#51A1DC" // collapsed package
              : d.children ? "#51A1DC" // expanded package
              : "#F94B4C"; // leaf node
        }

        function radius(d) {
            return d._children ? 8
            : d.children ? 8
            : 4
         }

      function ticked() {
        link
        .attr('x1', function(d){ return d.source.x; })
        .attr('y1', function(d){ return d.source.y; })
        .attr('x2', function(d){ return d.target.x; })
        .attr('y2', function(d){ return d.target.y; })

        node
        .attr('transform', function(d){ return `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})`})
      }

      function clicked(d) {
        if (!d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d.children = null;
            } else {
                d.children = d._children;
                d._children = null;
            }
            update()
        }
      }

      function dragstarted(d) {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart()
            d.fx = d.x
            d.fy = d.y
        }

        function dragged(d) {
            d.fx = d3.event.x
            d.fy = d3.event.y
        }

        function dragended(d) {
            if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0)
                d.fx = null
                d.fy = null
            }

            function flatten(root) {
                const nodes = []
                function recurse(node) {
                    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse)
                        if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
                    else ++i;
                    nodes.push(node)
                }
                recurse(root)
                return nodes
            }

            function zoomed() {
                svg.attr('transform', d3.event.transform)
            }


            function isConnected(a, b) {
                return linkedByIndex[`${a.index},${b.index}`] || linkedByIndex[`${b.index},${a.index}`] || a.index === b.index;
            }

            function fade(opacity) {
                return d => {
                    node.style('stroke-opacity', function (o) {
                        const thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
                        this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
                            return thisOpacity;
                        });

                        link.style('stroke-opacity', o => (o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity));

                    };
                }
        update(nodes, links_data) 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

**Edit1: in this js script links exist (when I drag a node others follow it), but are invisible:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // node data
        var nodes_data =  [
        {"name": "Travis", "sex": "M","size": 1983, 'col': "#1f77b4", 'shape': "circle"},
        {"name": "Rake", "sex": "M","size": 200, 'col': '#FF0000', 'shape': 'rect'},
        {"name": "Diana", "sex": "F","size": 15000, 'col': "#0000FF", 'shape': 'circle'},
        {"name": "Rachel", "sex": "F","size": 1800, 'col': "#0000FF", 'shape': 'rect'},
        {"name": "Shawn", "sex": "M","size": 1983, 'col': "#1f77b4", 'shape': 'circle'},
        {"name": "Emerald", "sex": "F","size": 10000, 'col': "#306754", 'shape': 'rect'}
        ]

        // links data 
        var links_data = [
            {"source": "Travis", "target": "Rake"},
            {"source": "Diana", "target": "Rake"},
            {"source": "Diana", "target": "Rachel"},
            {"source": "Rachel", "target": "Rake"},
            {"source": "Rachel", "target": "Shawn"},
            {"source": "Emerald", "target": "Rachel"}
        ]
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //toolpit 
        var tooltip = d3.select("body")
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("opacity", 0);

        //svg size
        const width = 1000,
        height = 1000;

        // Allow zoom
        const transform = d3.zoomIdentity;

        // Find connected nodes
        var linkedByIndex = {};

        // Append svg info
        const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
        .call(d3.zoom().scaleExtent([1/2, 8]).on('zoom', zoomed))
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(40,0)');

        // graph simulation
        const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force('link', 
            d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.name; }).strength(0.1)
            .distance(function(d) { return radius(d.source.value / 2) + radius(d.target.value / 2); })
            //.strength(function(d) {return 0.75; })
          )
        .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-15).distanceMax(300))
        .force('center', d3.forceCenter( width/2, height/4 ))
        .on('tick', ticked)

        // Function to update graph informations (nodes positions, links....)
        function update(nodes_data, links_data) {

            //Extract links source and target information
            link = svg.append()                 
                .attr('class', 'link')
                .selectAll('path')  
                .data(links_data)                   
                    .enter().append("svg:path")         
                    .style('stroke', 'black')
                    .style('opacity', 0.2)
                    .style('fill', 'none')
                    .style("stroke-width", '2px');

            // Add nodes to svg
            node = svg
                .selectAll('.nodes_data')
                .data(nodes_data, function(d){ return d.id });

            node.exit().remove()

            // Custumzie nodes
            const nodeEnter = node
                .enter()
                .append('g')
                .attr('class', 'node')
                .attr("d",function(d) {return d.shape;}) // PB de shape des noeuds
                .attr('stroke', function (d) { return d.col; })
                .attr('stroke-width', 1)
                .style("fill", function (d) { return d.col; })
                .on("mouseover", focus)
                .on('mouseover.tooltip', function(d) {
                    tooltip.transition()
                    .duration(300)
                    .style("opacity", 0.9);
                    tooltip.html("Label:" + d.name + "<p/>Degree:" + d.size)
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 10) + "px");
                })
                .on('mouseover.fade', fade(0.1))
                .on("mouseout.tooltip", function() {
                    tooltip.transition()
                    .duration(100)
                    .style("opacity", 0);
                })
                .on('mouseout.fade', fade(1))
                .on("mousemove", function() {
                    tooltip.style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 10) + "px");
                })
                .call(d3.drag()
                    .on('start', dragstarted)
                    .on('drag', dragged)
                    .on('end', dragended))


            // Draw nodes
            nodeEnter.append('circle')
                .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; })               
                .style('text-anchor', function(d){ return d.children ? 'end' : 'start'; })
                .text(function(d){ return d.name })


            node = nodeEnter.merge(node)
            simulation.nodes(nodes_data)
            simulation.force("link").links(links_data);
        }




        function radius(d) {
            return d._children ? 8
            : d.children ? 8
            : 4
         }

      function ticked() {
         link.attr("d", function(d) {
            var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            return "M" + 
            d.source.x + "," + 
            d.source.y + "A" + 
            dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + 
            d.target.x + "," + 
            d.target.y;
        });

        node
        .attr('transform', function(d){ return `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})`})
      }

      function clicked(d) {
        if (!d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d.children = null;
            } else {
                d.children = d._children;
                d._children = null;
            }
            update()
        }
      }

      function dragstarted(d) {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart()
            d.fx = d.x
            d.fy = d.y
        }

        function dragged(d) {
            d.fx = d3.event.x
            d.fy = d3.event.y
        }

        function dragended(d) {
            if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0)
                d.fx = null
                d.fy = null
            }

            function flatten(root) {
                const nodes = []
                function recurse(node) {
                    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse)
                        if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
                    else ++i;
                    nodes.push(node)
                }
                recurse(root)
                return nodes
            }

            function zoomed() {
                svg.attr('transform', d3.event.transform)
            }


            function isConnected(a, b) {
                return linkedByIndex[`${a.index},${b.index}`] || linkedByIndex[`${b.index},${a.index}`] || a.index === b.index;
            }

            function fade(opacity) {
                return d => {
                    node.style('stroke-opacity', function (o) {
                        const thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
                        this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
                            return thisOpacity;
                        });

                        link.style('stroke-opacity', o => (o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity));

                    };
                }
        update(nodes_data, links_data) 
    </script>
```

Comment: Could you put your code into a pen for us to play with? I'm not getting anything at all - which version of d3 are you using?

Comment: hi, I use d v5. I added the code in code pen but as for you it shows nothing... I continue to work on the code and now I have links but invisible even declaring their stroke: codepen.io/sebastiansosa/pen/zYOdXqE

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are identifying your nodes by `id` property which is missing. Since your links are using names as references you should change the nodes iteration to:

```
node = svg
  .selectAll('.nodes_data')
  .data(nodes_data, function(d){ return d.name });
```

The example you posted is generating ids for the nodes in the `flatten` function in order to generate the references.